# How could I make a Wi-Fi Hotspot with WEP security, or none?

Tags: networking, security, wifi, software-rec

Brief history, but when Nintendo made the DS Classic, they only included WEP support for wifi. In the search of using a community DNS server to receive Pokemon I have found no device in my house which can produce a Wi-Fi signal with either WEP security, or no security at all

The most I can do is a Wi-Fi hotspot on my phone as it can do no security, but it not without using a mobile network with data, which is just too expensive where I live.

And no, my router's guest option forces WPA2, and cannot be unsecured. The windows laptop I have cannot produce a hotspot without WPA2 either, at a driver level as I've read.

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which has wifi capabilities, and I'm looking for any possible way to produce a signal which would work in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nm-connection-editor` you can create a new wifi connection and set to Hotspot mode.

In ipv4 settings set to "Shared to other computers"

In WI-FI Security you can set as desired.

Because you are going to be using this with a older device make sure the band is set to 2.4GHz.

After you setup the hotspot to enable it you might need to go to your wifi settings on the Ubuntu box and "Connect" to it to enable it.